# How to run OLS Regression by using SPSS?

Tags: spss, least-squares

I need to conduct OLS regression by using SPSS for my thesis. I was wondering what are the steps in conducting OLS regression?

(1) SPSS - Analyze - Regression - Linear ? Is this correct?

(2) Where to put control variable? and what are the steps to run it?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi user24877, welcome to CrossValidated. Questions of the form "which software buttons do I press to do X" aren't usually [on topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) for CrossValidated, they're generally a better fit for stackoverflow. If you wish to flag your post for a moderator to move it, click 'flag' under your post.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes

(2) In the independent variables.

> and what are the steps to run it?

Once you've filled in the variables and organized to save any statistics you want, click "Ok".

[e.g.](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/multiple-regression-using-spss-statistics.php#procedure)  or [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EFXic4sGdE)

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if I put one of the control variable into the independent variables box, what will happen in the SPSS output? I mean how do I know the effect of the control variable? Also, should I put the control variable in a separate block? put it as the last block or the first block?

Comment: @user24877 See the link called "e.g." that Glen_b gave you. Scroll down to see the output table. For block, if you put A in block 1, and then B in block 2, then SPSS will run two models: first is A only, the second is A + B, so on so forth.